# Remove First and Last Double Quote From JSON Array

Tags: javascript

Here i have one big array that has multiple arrays inside. I need to remove double quotes from each array. I tried all different methods to pull out quotes but none seem to work.

Current code produces this result:

```
[
  ["1,jone,matt,ny,none,doctor"],
  ["2,maria,lura,nj,some,engineer"],
  ["3,paul,kirk,la,none,artist"]
]
```

I need it this way:

```
[
  [1,jone,matt,ny,none,doctor],
  [2,maria,lura,nj,some,engineer],
  [3,paul,kirk,la,none,artist]
]
```

```
    const storeArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

      var finalArray = results[i].id + "," + results[i].name + "," + results[i].lastname + "," + results[i].address + "," + results[i].status + "," + results[i].about;

      storeArray.push([finalArray]);
    }

    res.send(storeArray);
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of why the data is the way it is @RandyCasburn. It just solves a new problem that probably doesn't have to exist.

Comment: @Andy - we don't get to decide what the input state is for the OP - and the OP never really declared the required output. Whether that presents a new problem for the OP is purely predicated on what the OP truly wants. Hence why I did not write that as an answer.

Comment: @Andy - for example - OP states "_I need to remove double quotes from each array_" - So what does that actually mean given the data that is represented in the Q?

Comment: Even if you make those into element-separated arrays instead of strings you'll still have quotes because some of those items are actual strings.

Comment: `storeArray.push(Object.values(results[i]));` [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: _"So what does that actually mean given the data that is represented in the Q?_: which is why your original comment was misleading.

Comment: hi @RandyCasburn as you can see I have three arrays in the example above. I need to get rid of double quotes [" ... "] that present in each of 3 arrays. :)

Comment: @Andy - got it.

Comment: @D.M. - this --> `storeArray.push(Object.values(results[i]));` inside the `for` loop should do what you need.j

Comment: This: "_I need it this way_" - that is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: it's an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating strings as the first element of an array instead of an array of elements. You'll still have to contend with quotes because some of your data are strings - there's no getting round that - but this is closer to what you want.

```js
const results = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Andy', lastname: 'Jones', address: '999 Letsbe Avenue', status: 5, about: 'About' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Sue', lastname: 'Barlow', address: '1 Fifth Street', status: 1, about: 'Another about' }
];

const storeArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

  storeArray.push([
    results[i].id,
    results[i].name,
    results[i].lastname,
    results[i].address,
    results[i].status,
    results[i].about
  ]);

}

console.log(storeArray);
```